# BackgroundWorker UI doesn't update progress in Windows Phone 7

Tags: windows-phone-7, backgroundworker

In Windows Phone 7, I'm trying to display the status of some LINQ queries.
I'm using BackgroundWorker. I see the progress update in the Debug windows but not in the UI (TextBlock4.Text). It seems that the progress is updated after all the queries are over. Also the UI is not responsive while running the queries. How can I avoid UI freeze? How can I display the progress in the UI? Is there another way to display queries progress?

```
Partial Public Class pagInvoicesReport
Inherits PhoneApplicationPage

Private WithEvents mWorker As New BackgroundWorker()

Private nJan As Nullable(Of Decimal) = 0
Private nFeb As Nullable(Of Decimal) = 0
Private nMar As Nullable(Of Decimal) = 0
Private nApr As Nullable(Of Decimal) = 0
Private nMay As Nullable(Of Decimal) = 0
Private nJun As Nullable(Of Decimal) = 0
Private nJul As Nullable(Of Decimal) = 0
Private nAug As Nullable(Of Decimal) = 0
Private nSept As Nullable(Of Decimal) = 0
Private nOct As Nullable(Of Decimal) = 0
Private nNov As Nullable(Of Decimal) = 0
Private nDec As Nullable(Of Decimal) = 0

Public Sub New()
    InitializeComponent()
    mWorker.WorkerReportsProgress = True
End Sub

Private Sub startButton_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles startButton.Click
    mWorker.RunWorkerAsync()
End Sub

Private Sub mWorker_ProgressChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As ProgressChangedEventArgs) Handles mWorker_ProgressChanged
    TextBlock4.Text = e.ProgressPercentage.ToString() & "%"
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(e.ProgressPercentage.ToString() & "%")
End Sub

Private Sub GetGraphValues() Handles mWorker.DoWork
    System.Windows.Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke( _
            Sub()
                Using theDB As New appContext("Data Source=isostore:/theDB.sdf")
                    Try
                        If (Aggregate r In theDB.InvoicesRecords Where r.InvoiceDateTime.Month = 1 And r.InvoiceDateTime.Year = 2012 And r.MainID = 1 Into Sum(CType(r.Cost, Decimal?))) IsNot Nothing Then
                            nJan = (Aggregate r In theDB.InvoicesRecords Where r.InvoiceDateTime.Month = 1 And r.InvoiceDateTime.Year = 2012 And r.MainID = 1 Into Sum(CType(r.Cost, Decimal?)))
                        Else
                            nJan = 0
                        End If
                    Catch ex As Exception
                        MessageBox.Show("There was an error!" & vbCrLf & ex.Message, "Error!", MessageBoxButton.OK)
                    End Try
                End Using
            End Sub)

    mWorker.ReportProgress(8)

    System.Windows.Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke( _
        Sub()
            Using theDB As New appContext("Data Source=isostore:/theDB.sdf")
                Try
                    If (Aggregate r In theDB.InvoicesRecords Where r.InvoiceDateTime.Month = 2 And r.InvoiceDateTime.Year = 2012 And r.MainID = 1 Into Sum(CType(r.Cost, Decimal?))) IsNot Nothing Then
                        nFeb = (Aggregate r In theDB.InvoicesRecords Where r.InvoiceDateTime.Month = 2 And r.InvoiceDateTime.Year = 2012 And r.MainID = 1 Into Sum(CType(r.Cost, Decimal?)))
                    Else
                        nFeb = 0
                    End If
                Catch ex As Exception
                    MessageBox.Show("There was an error!" & vbCrLf & ex.Message, "Error!", MessageBoxButton.OK)
                End Try
            End Using
        End Sub)

    mWorker.ReportProgress(17)



    System.Windows.Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke( _
        Sub()
            Using theDB As New appContext("Data Source=isostore:/theDB.sdf")
                Try
                    If (Aggregate r In theDB.InvoicesRecords Where r.InvoiceDateTime.Month = 12 And r.InvoiceDateTime.Year = 2012 And r.MainID = 1 Into Sum(CType(r.Cost, Decimal?))) IsNot Nothing Then
                        nDec = (Aggregate r In theDB.InvoicesRecords Where r.InvoiceDateTime.Month = 12 And r.InvoiceDateTime.Year = 2012 And r.MainID = 1 Into Sum(CType(r.Cost, Decimal?)))
                    Else
                        nDec = 0
                    End If
                Catch ex As Exception
                    MessageBox.Show("There was an error!" & vbCrLf & ex.Message, "Error!", MessageBoxButton.OK)
                End Try
            End Using
        End Sub)
    mWorker.ReportProgress(100)
End Sub
```

End Class

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are issuing the work to be done on the UI thread. You're DoWork method should not Invoke the Dispatcher. This will put all of the work on the UI thread rather than the BackgroundWorker thread.

**UPDATE:** Just noticed that you are access member variables. Not recommended to do that, your background worker should return the results it calculates, here is a simple example showing results returned in an List (I'm not a VB expert, so bear with me). When the worker completes, take the result and replace your properties

Try changing your DoWork handler to:

```
Private Sub GetGraphValues(args as DoWorkEventArgs) Handles mWorker.DoWork
    Dim list as List<Decimal>();
    Dim jan as Decimal
    Dim feb as Decimal
    Dim dec as Dicimal
    Using theDB As New appContext("Data Source=isostore:/theDB.sdf")
        Try
            If (Aggregate r In theDB.InvoicesRecords Where r.InvoiceDateTime.Month = 1 And r.InvoiceDateTime.Year = 2012 And r.MainID = 1 Into Sum(CType(r.Cost, Decimal?))) IsNot Nothing Then
                jan = (Aggregate r In theDB.InvoicesRecords Where r.InvoiceDateTime.Month = 1 And r.InvoiceDateTime.Year = 2012 And r.MainID = 1 Into Sum(CType(r.Cost, Decimal?)))
            Else
                jan = 0
            End If
        Catch ex As Exception
            ' Showing messageBox SHOULD be shown on UI thread
            System.Windows.Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke( _
            Sub()
                MessageBox.Show("There was an error!" & vbCrLf & ex.Message, "Error!", MessageBoxButton.OK)
            End Sub)
        End Try
    End Using
    list.Add(jan);

    mWorker.ReportProgress(8)

    Using theDB As New appContext("Data Source=isostore:/theDB.sdf")
        Try
            If (Aggregate r In theDB.InvoicesRecords Where r.InvoiceDateTime.Month = 2 And r.InvoiceDateTime.Year = 2012 And r.MainID = 1 Into Sum(CType(r.Cost, Decimal?))) IsNot Nothing Then
                feb = (Aggregate r In theDB.InvoicesRecords Where r.InvoiceDateTime.Month = 2 And r.InvoiceDateTime.Year = 2012 And r.MainID = 1 Into Sum(CType(r.Cost, Decimal?)))
            Else
                feb = 0
            End If
        Catch ex As Exception
            ' Showing messageBox SHOULD be shown on UI thread
            System.Windows.Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke( _
            Sub()
                MessageBox.Show("There was an error!" & vbCrLf & ex.Message, "Error!", MessageBoxButton.OK)
            End Sub)
        End Try
    End Using
    list.Add(feb)

    mWorker.ReportProgress(17)

    Using theDB As New appContext("Data Source=isostore:/theDB.sdf")
        Try
            If (Aggregate r In theDB.InvoicesRecords Where r.InvoiceDateTime.Month = 12 And r.InvoiceDateTime.Year = 2012 And r.MainID = 1 Into Sum(CType(r.Cost, Decimal?))) IsNot Nothing Then
                dec = (Aggregate r In theDB.InvoicesRecords Where r.InvoiceDateTime.Month = 12 And r.InvoiceDateTime.Year = 2012 And r.MainID = 1 Into Sum(CType(r.Cost, Decimal?)))
            Else
                dec = 0
            End If
        Catch ex As Exception
            ' Showing messageBox SHOULD be shown on UI thread
            System.Windows.Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke( _
            Sub()
                MessageBox.Show("There was an error!" & vbCrLf & ex.Message, "Error!", MessageBoxButton.OK)
            End Sub)
        End Try
    End Using
    list.Add(dec)

    mWorker.ReportProgress(100)
    args.Result = list
End Sub
```

Comment: If I'm not using a Dispatcher for the LINQ query I get an error: Invalid cross-thread access.

Comment: all LINQ i see is wrapped in Dispatcher.BeginInvoke. Am I missing something?

Comment: when I remove Dispatcher.BeginInvoke wrapper, I get 'Invalid cross-thread access' error..

Comment: should I use Dispatcher.BeginInvoke in the mWorker_ProgressChanged sub?

Comment: You shouldn't have to. It should fire on the UI thread, but it also doesn't hurt. Just do not invoke work on the UI thread from the background worker. See my changes to the answer

Comment: I've tried your example, and after a few adjustments from C# to VB, I get 'Invalid cross-thread access.' error

Comment: I've read on other posts that I should wrap it with Dispatcher.BeginInvoke

Comment: what happens when you pass the autoMinderDB as a parameter to the RunWorkerAsync method and then access it from the DoWorkEventArgs?

Comment: I've tried passing theDB as parameter to the RunWorkerAsync (e.Argument) but I still get 'Invalid cross-thread access.' error